# Typeorm - How to get rows where given user belongs to an array?

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

Model

```
@Entity('bill')
export class Bill {
  @Column()
  title: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  description?: string;

  @ManyToMany(() => User, { nullable: true })
  @JoinTable()
  friends?: User[];
}
```

I want to get all the rows where friends include a given user. The approach I tried -

```
const bills = await this.billRepo.find({
   where: {
     friends: {
        id: user.id, 
     },
   },
   relations: ['friends']
});
```

works perfectly but doesn't return the complete friends array. It just returns the user we are using in where clause

Answer (score 0):

Your following code will generate a SQL query with a where clause that only keep the user corresponding to "user.id".

```
const bills = await this.billRepo.find({
   where: {
     friends: {
        id: user.id, 
     },
   },
   relations: ['friends']
});
```

I see 2 simple options

1)
You make a first query to retrieve only the ids of the bills.
You make a second query to retrieve bills correspondings with the ids you retrieve in the first query.

Something like:

```
const bills = await this.billRepo.find({
    where: {
        friends: {
            id: user.id,
        },
    },
    relations: ['friends']
});

const idsBills = bills.map((bill) => {
    return bill.id;

const finalBills = await this.billRepo.find({
    where: {
        id: idsBills,
    },
    relations: ['friends']
});
```

PRO: really easy to understand.
CON: not perf optimal

2. You do the same using a subquery

Comment: Still can't believe there isn't any direct solution to this.